# I am facing problrm when a run my hello.py file at google apps engine

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

I am facing problrm when a run my hello.py file at google apps engine

```
import webapp2 

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler): 
    def get(self): 
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, World!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage), ], debug=True)
```

> Error: Server Error
>
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>   Please try again in 30 seconds.

Comment: Can you provide some code snippet of hello.py? Also some logs of the error would be helpful.

Comment: import webapp2
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
self.response.write('Hello, World!')
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/

Comment: You saved it in plain text right? Also did you do the config file?

Comment: I have two files hello.py and app.yaml
app.yaml contain
application: hello
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: hello.py

Comment: You should edit your question and add the code in there, not in comments. The script value in the `app.yaml` should be `hello.app`, not `hello.py`.

Comment: In addition to the above comments, what is the error message in your logs.  That will actually explain what the problem is.